# Stop FragmentPagerAdapter from creating all its fragments at once

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

So I have bottom navigation bar with 4 fragments for each tab, and inside each one I call an API request to fetch some data, but the problem is each time I press any tab of the bar, at least two of the fragments gets created and they call their own method and by extension they fires the API request..! I just want the fragment that I select to be instantiated.!

I know the adapter behaves like this to pre-render the fragment to ensure better transaction between tabs and whatnot..! but I really can't afford to call multiple api calls with each select..!

**Adapter**

```
public class My_PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
                       // I've tried FragmentStatePagerAdapter but same thing

  public My_PagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
      case 0:
         new MyFragment_1();
      case 1:
         new MyFragment_2();
      case 2:
         new MyFragment_3();
      case 3:
         new MyFragment_4();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 4;
  }
}
```

**Edit**

This how I call the adapter..

```
ViewPager viewPager = main.findViewById(R.id.vp); 
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); 
viewPager.setAdapter(new My_PagerAdapter (getChildFragmentManager()));
navigationTabBar.setModels(models); // just UI stuff for each tab offered by the bottom navigation bar library, 
navigationTabBar.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is exactly an issue that i faced. The solution i have does not stop the viewpager from creating the fragments but it will stop the calls to network api.

Heres the gist:

1) Create an interface

```
public interface ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface {
  void onResumeAndShowFragment();
  void onPauseAndHideFragment();
  //void refreshFragment();
}
```

2) modify your FragmentPagerAdapter to override the onInstantiateItem method

Here each Fragment will have a weakReference declared inside the Adapter class in order to store a reference to the fragments created

```
    @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){

    Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            xyzWeakReference=null;
            xyzFragmentWeakReference=new WeakReference<>((xyz)createdFragment);
            break;

        case 1:
            xyz1WeakReference=null;
            xyz1WeakReference=new WeakReference<>((xyz1WeakReference)createdFragment);
            break;

    }

    return createdFragment;
};
```

3) Inside the FragmentPagerAdapter, add the following method in order to fetch the weak reference of the fragment in picture

```
    public Fragment getFragmentAtGivenPosition(int i){
    switch (i){
        case 0:
            if(xyzFragmentWeakReference == null){
                return null;
            }
            return xyzFragmentWeakReference.get();
        case 1:
            if(xyz1FragmentWeakReference == null){
                return null;
            }
            return xyz1FragmentWeakReference.get();

    }
}
```

4) Now in the activity where the TabLayout is created and the view pager instantiated, attach a listener to the TabLayout for listening to tab changes

```
        tabLayout_bookmarks.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(final TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            //let the instantiateItem have some time to be called by the adapter

            currentFragmentIndex = tab.getPosition();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface currentFragment = (ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface)btca.getFragmentAtGivenPosition(tab.getPosition());

                    if(currentFragment!=null){
                        currentFragment.onResumeAndShowFragment();
                    }else{
                        //Log.d("FragmentCreate","Current fragment is null and fucked up in adapter");

                        //if it is null ... that means the adapter hasn't yet called instantiate item ... this internally calls get item any way
                        //.....

                        //This shouldn't really hit but in case it does ... keep a handler in order to ensure that everything is created
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface localFragment  = (ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface)btca.getItem(tab.getPosition());
                                //getItem never returns a null fragment unless supplied a horrendous value for position
                                //by the time these 50 ms pass, the instantiate item should surely have been called
                                //else it will be an empty space ... no crash though
                                localFragment.onResumeAndShowFragment();
                            }
                        },50);
                    }

                }
            },100);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(final TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface currentFragment = (ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface)btca.getFragmentAtGivenPosition(tab.getPosition());
                    if(currentFragment!=null){
                        currentFragment.onPauseAndHideFragment();
                    }else{
                        //Log.d("FragmentCreateTab","the fucking fragment was null");
                        //if it is null ... that means the adapter hasn't yet called instantiate item ... this internally calls get item any way
                        //.....

                        //This shouldn't really hit but in case it does ... keep a handler in order to ensure that everything is created
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface localFragment  = (ViewPagerLifeCycleManagerInterface)btca.getItem(tab.getPosition());
                                //getItem never returns a null fragment unless supplied a horrendous value for position
                                //by the time these 50 ms pass, the instantiate item should surely have been called
                                //else it will be an empty space ... no crash though
                                localFragment.onPauseAndHideFragment();
                            }
                        },50);

                    }

                }
            },100);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
```

5) In each of the Fragments inside the Viewpager, implement the Interface we created in step 1 and override the methods.

Create a boolean variable in each fragment amIVisible... This will help decide when the fragment is visible and when it can call the network api

a) here for the first fragment in viewpager, i.e at 0 index, the network api call has to happen immediately after the view gets created. This fragment is obviously visible by default. This is written inside onCreateView method

```
        if(dataList!=null && dataList.size()==0) {
        if (savedInstanceState==null) {
            //your api call to load from net
        } else {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("savedState")) {
                //If you have saved data in state save, load it here
            } else {
                //only fire the async if the current fragment is the one visible, else the onResumeAndShowFragment will trigger the same async when it becomes visible
                if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("amIVisible")) {
                    //Load data from net
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The other methods are as follows for the first fragment

```
    @Override
public void onResumeAndShowFragment() {
    amIVisible=true;


    if(dataList!=null && dataList.size()==0){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Load data from net if data was not found,
                //This basically means auto refresh when user scrolls back and the fragment had no data
            }
        },400);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPauseAndHideFragment() {
    amIVisible=false;
}
```

Here i have overriden onSaveInstanceState method and saved the value of amIVisible and savedState is a boolean which indicates if the list has at least 1 item or not.

b) For the other fragments, Data will be loaded by the following process

```
        if(savedInstance!=null){

        if (savedInstance.getBoolean("savedState")) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //load data from saved State
                }
            },100);

        } else {
            //only fire the async if the current fragment is the one visible, else the onResumeAndShowFragment will trigger the same async when it becomes visible


            if (savedInstance.getBoolean("amIVisible")) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //load data from net
                    }
                },100);

            }
        }
    }
```

The interface methods are the same for the other fragments.

This is pretty complicated but does the job. The weak references inside the adapter even allow garbage collection and avoid context leaks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same exact issue on a project that I'm working on

The solution for me was to add the API calls on the OnResume method in each fragment. 
That way they will only be triggered when the fragment is fully visible.

Check out the [fragment lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ3QW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have one activity in which i am using a viewpager with bottom navigation.
There is a four fragment A, B,C,D.
When i change the screen from bottom tab (A to B).
onResume method of B is not triggered .But i want to hit the api on that page(B). So Solution is -:

Add this line before setAdapter of view pager in activity.
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(number_of_fragment); // example: number_of_fragment = 4

This method not load all the fragment at a same time.

And check log in onResume method of screen B. Can update the data in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).